# How to install twitter kit using fabric plugin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-login

I have recently install fabric plugin in Android studio and try to install twitter kit. But i could't find twitter kit in fabric. As I remember previously it was shown in all kits page.
[image]

Please guide me how to install twitter kit using fabric.

Comment: can you please share your answer that how you solved your problem,because i am facing same issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twitter sold Fabric to Google. A number of changes will occur in Fabric, because of this. One of them is that they removed Twitterkit from Fabric. You can still install it, however not via Fabric.
Here you can find the [Twitter kit documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/overview)

You will also have to update your applications with TwitterKit build in.
It is all explained in [this blogpost](https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2017/Introducing-Twitter-Kit-3.html). They sent an email to the admin of your Fabrics organization account.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same problem, so used following code .. refer the following link hope will help you all....

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834404/5371709